# Llaves primarias y llaves foráneas de SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una duda en la que espero puedan ayudarme. E creado unas tablas en SQL SERVER...

```
 CREATE TABLE FamiliasSoluciones(
idFamilia INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
NumeroFamilia AS (Right('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, idFamilia),(2)) + 'S'),
NombreFamilia NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE NumerosParte(
idNumParte INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
NumeroParte NVARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
Descripcion NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
Referencia NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
Unidad NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SubEns NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PrecioUSD MONEY NOT NULL,
PrecioMXN MONEY NOT NULL,
Observaciones NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
Revision NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
idFamilia INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (idFamilia) REFERENCES FamiliasSolutum(idFamilia),
);
```

Al querer insertar un registro en mi tabla NumerosParte tengo que agregar el **idFamilia**, pero lo que deseo es poder agregar el **NumeroFamilia**
¿Eso puede ser posible?

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo lo visual con lo interno. Internamente, debes de guardar el ID, pero visualmente puedes mostrar lo que quieras de la familia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede, pero tienes que hacer algunos pequeños ajustes en la definición.

Lo primero, la columna NumeroFamilia, tiene que ser persistida. Además debe de ser clave, por tanto podemos aplicarle una constraint Unique.

```
CREATE TABLE FamiliasSoluciones(
idFamilia INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
NumeroFamilia AS (Right('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, idFamilia),(2)) + 'S') PERSISTED,
NombreFamilia NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);
```

Lo único que varía respecto al script, es el uso de `PERSISTED`

Ahora le añadimos la restricción.

```
ALTER TABLE FamiliasSoluciones
Add Constraint uk_FamiliaSol_NumeroFam unique (NumeroFamilia);
```

En la creación de la otra tabla, hay que apuntar a esa columna.

```
CREATE TABLE NumerosParte(
idNumParte INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
NumeroParte NVARCHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
Descripcion NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
Referencia NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
Unidad NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SubEns NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PrecioUSD MONEY NOT NULL,
PrecioMXN MONEY NOT NULL,
Observaciones NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
Revision NVARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
NumeroFamilia varchar(3) NOT NULL);
```

Ojo, que el tipo de dato, es de una longitud de 3 y eso te dará problemas.

Añadimos la Foreign Key

```
Alter Table NumerosParte 
Add Constraint FK_NumerosParte_FamSol 
    FOREIGN KEY (NumeroFamilia) REFERENCES FamiliasSoluciones(NumeroFamilia);
```

Insertamos una linea.

```
INSERT INTO FamiliasSoluciones (NombreFamilia)
VALUES
('FAMILIA1');
```

[image: res]

Insertamos un NumeroParte

```
INSERT INTO NumerosParte (
NumeroParte,
Descripcion,
Referencia ,
Unidad ,
SubEns ,
PrecioUSD,
PrecioMXN,
Observaciones,
Revision,
NumeroFamilia
)
Values
(N'0001',
N'DES',
N'REF1',
N'UNID1',
N'SBU1',
10,
5,
N'Obs',
N'RE',
'01S');
```

[image: Res2]

El problema es que va a pasar cuando tengas 100 familias, y el campo necesite más anchura.

Quizá deberías de preveer eso, y darle más anchura ya de mano, si es que lo vas a necesitar.

[Campos calculados o persistidos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2022/06/19/campos-calculados-o-persistidos/)

Comment: Me encanto tu respuesta, me sirve muchísimo. ¡Muchas gracias!